# PHP Concatenation with JS Onclick Event

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is driving me nuts.

I have a button on my php template

```
echo '<a href="'. esc_url($action_link) .'" class="action_button'. esc_attr($action_class) .'" '. wp_kses_data($action_target) .'>'. wp_kses(mfn_opts_get('header-action-title'), mfn_allowed_html('button')) .'</a>';
```

And I need to attach the following Analytics event tracker code:

```
onclick="gtag('event', 'clic', { 'event_category': 'EVENTCAT', 'event_label': 'EVENTLABEL'});"
```

Sounds not too hard, but im not managing to make this work, after I have tried a lot of different combinations.

Is there any way to just escape everything?

Comment: None of that _needs_ any additional escaping, so theoretically you can just copy&paste it into the right position, and be done with it. If you want to use `esc_attr`, then you need to feed it the actual attribute value only, not the whole `attributename="value"` thing.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @04FS . If I copy paste it before the href I get a blank screen on my website, so I assume thats because something has to be escaped or concatenated.

Comment: @PatrickBen What does the anchor/action_link look like in the output HTML?

Comment: Well inside that echo statement, that already uses single quotes as string delimiters, the single quotes inside the value of the attribute you want to insert need to be escaped of course. `echo '<a onclick="gtag(\'event\', …);" href="`

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
echo '<a 
    onclick="gtag(\'event\', \'clic\', { \'event_category\': \'EVENTCAT\', \'event_label\': \'EVENTLABEL\'});" 
    href="'. esc_url($action_link) .'" 
    class="action_button'. esc_attr($action_class) .'" '. wp_kses_data($action_target) .'>'.
    wp_kses(mfn_opts_get('header-action-title'), mfn_allowed_html('button')) 
    .'</a>';
```